# How to add an input file name to multiple output files in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

The question might be trivial. I'm trying to figure out a way to add a part of my input file name to multiple outputs generated by the following awk script.

Script:

```
zcat $1 | BEGIN {
    # the number of sequences per file
    if (!N) N=10000;

    # file prefix
    if (!prefix) prefix = "seq";    

    # file suffix
    if (!suffix) suffix = "fa";

    # this keeps track of the sequences
    count = 0
}

# skip empty lines at the beginning
/^$/ { next; }

# act on fasta header
/^>/ {
    if (count % N == 0) {
        if (output) close(output)
        output = sprintf("%s%07d.%s", prefix, count, suffix)        
    }
    print > output
    count ++
    next
}

# write the fasta body into the file
{
    print >> output
}
```

The input in `$1` variable is `30_C_283_1_5.9.fa.gz`

The output files generated by the script are 
`myseq0000000.fa`, `myseq1000000.fa` and so on....

I would like the output to be
`30_C_283_1_5.9_myseq000000.fa`, `30_C_283_1_5.9_myseq100000.fa`....

Looking forward for some inputs in this regard.

Comment: If you put your file names on the command line instead of piping them to `awk` you can access them via `ARGV[1]` for the first file name, `ARGV[2]..ARGV[n]` for files 1..n.

Comment: Use FILENAME vairable. `print > FILENAME`

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to direct the output from inside the Awk script:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html